# Rails 4 display paperclip temp file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have a form and a button that displays a preview of the page before it gets submitted. I can display all the attributes of my model but cannot, for the love of me, get the paperclip attachment to display.
The create action for my Event model is like the following, if the preview button is clicked, I render the preview.html.erb view and display my event attributes to the user:

```
def create
 @event = Event.new(event_params)
 if params[:preview]
   render 'preview'
   return
 else
   #process normally and save
 end
end
```

The Event model has an attached file 'image' through Paperclip:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_attached_file :image, :styles => {:gallery => "640x320#", :thumb => "100x100#"}
end
```

In the preview.html.erb view I am trying to display the temporary file that Paperclip creates before save, however this is not working. In the view I am using this:

```
<%= image_tag @event.image.queued_for_write[:gallery].path %>
```

However, when the preview page is rendered the image is missing. Can anybody help me with displaying Paperclip images before the model is saved? How can I access the temp file and display it in the view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript. Your form should look like this:

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar, id: 'avatar-preview' %>
<%= f.file_field :avatar, onchange: "readUploadImage(this)" %>
```

Your JS:

```
function readUploadImage(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#avatar-preview')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(300)
                .height(300);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that the file input fields are nested fields, so when I want to add multiple pictures I will end up with several input fields with the same id "#avatar_preview".

Comment: In that case, simply create an image_tag preview element for each picture you want to upload, and perform updates accordingly.